# In Bash scripting, what's a good way to append multiple files of the same names together?

Tags: bash, directory

So, I'm building my first script, it's to unzip files from two different directories and merge said directories together and then to append all the files of the same name together. The only part I'm struggling with is the appending multiple files of the same name together. What's a good way to go about that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the directory structure of each archive, is it the same? In that case, assume unzipp'ed files are in `a/` and `b/`, do something like this:

```
mkdir c
for f in a/*; do
  cat a/"$f" b/"$f" > c/"$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cp` for the second directory, do

```
for file in source/* ; do
    cat "$file" >> target/"${file#*/}"
done
```